# Azure SQL Server database user login disabled after DACPAC publish

Tags: dacpac, sqlpackage

I have CICD pipeline setup for deploying the database using DACPAC.

I have arguments for `sqlpackge.exe` here

```
/p:ExcludeObjectTypes="Users;RoleMembership;Logins;ServerRoles;ServerRoleMembership"
```

This works fine, the users for the database is disabled with a red X after deploying. User cannot login after deploy

```
GRANT
CONNECT 
TO 
TheUser1
```

About code could enable the user again, but I don't want to touch any user permission in my pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/p:ExcludeObjectTypes="Permissions"`
exclude Permissions will not revoke connect the user